# Select field on update form do not preselect existing values, for project created with Roo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have created my first MVC Roo project with MongoDB. Few fields in an entity are defined as set

```
field set --type ~.model.Release --fieldName releases
```

Everything works fine, except for the update form. If I try to update an existing object the selection of referenced objects is not maintained in the UI. Is this a known issue? How do I fix this?

I tried investigating the HTML output, and observed that none of the option tag under select tag has 'selected' attribute. On the controller side the model attributes are populated as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out to be an object comparison issue. Each of my bean classes needed equals method to be implemented, and everything now working fine.